# Appcelerator : How do I change the IOS simulator in titanium?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

How do I change the IOS simulator in titanium?

I want to start up in the iPhone 11 simulator, but the iPhone SE starts up.

Comment: are you using Studio, VSCode, Atom or CLI? Normally in all cases you can select the simulator. E.g. in CLI `appc ti build -p ios -C ?` and select the simulator in the menu. In VSCode/Atom you have buttons for them

Comment: Thank you.
I was running it in the CLI.
I solved it with appc ti build -p ios -C.

Comment: awesome! I'll added it as an answer so you can mark it and other people will find it easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the CLI you can run:

```
appc ti build -p ios -C ?
```

and will get a small menu where you can select your device.

Other editors (e.g. VSCode or Atom) have buttons to choose the simulator/emulator you want to run on.